# How to remove space from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, isnull

Example

```
col1        col 2       col3
300         Broad       ST

,(IsNUll((Cast(FLOOR(col1) as CHAR (7) )),'')  + ' ' + IsNull(col2,'') + ' ' + isnull(col3,'')) as col4
```

result i get is

```
300     Broad ST
```

what i want is

```
300 Broad St.
```

there is 4 or 5 space between 300 and Broad

the data type for col1 is numeric and for col 2 and 3 is nvarchar. I don't want to change the data type.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the qustion.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like SQL Server.  If so:

```
stuff(coalesce(' ' + Cast(floor(col1) as varchar(7)), '') +
      coalesce(' ' + col2, '') + 
      coalesce(' ' + col3, ''),
      1, 1, '') as col4
```