# how to remove space from SQL when joining multi columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
,Rtrim (Ltrim(IsNUll((Cast(FLOOR([COL1]) as CHAR (5))),'')+' '
+ isnull([COL2],'') + ' ' + (IsNull([COL3],'')))) as COLALL
```

The two outputs I get :

Output #1:

```
12345 main Street
```

Output #2:

```
12    main Street
```

Output #1 is good because `COL1` has 5 characters.
Output #2 is not good cause `COL1` has 2 characters.

How to make it so even when `COL1` has 2 characters I get the following result:

```
12 main Street
```

Comment: What result are you getting now? Is "12 main Street" the correct result or the incorrect result?

Comment: That is incorrect because i get 12    Main street. some how when i post my question the space got removed

Comment: after 12 there is 3 spaces then Main street

Comment: I fixed the formatting so you can see the spaces now

Comment: Exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006348/how-to-remove-space-from-sql) a year ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If you want to bring together the different elements, I would recommend:

```
select stuff( (coalesce(' ' + Cast(FLOOR([COL1]) as VARCHAR(5)), '') +
               coalesce(' ' + col2, '') +
               coalesce(' ' + col3, '')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            )
```

This is the simplest way that I've found to concatenate columns that might be `NULL` with separators in SQL Server.  Note that for the special case of space, you can use `ltrim()` instead.  `stuff()` is more general because the approach will work with any separators.

I should also note that a big part of your problem is using `char()` rather than `varchar()` for the number.  `char()` pads out numbers with spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just replaced CHAR with VARCHAR it did work. i will keep your way in my notes for future. Thank you for your help